# Не получается создать virtualenv

Tags: python

После того, как я перешел на 64bit Python, возникла проблема при создании virtualenv. Выводится это:

```
created virtual environment in 1935ms CPython3Windows(dest=P:\test5\venv, clear=False, global=False) with seeder FromAppData pip=latest setuptools=latest wheel=latest app_data_dir=C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\seed-v1 via=copy
```

Хотя venv нормально создается.
P.s. я и вроде понимаю, что создается virtualenv,но при этом у меня не получается активировать окружение

Answer (score 1):

Для начала хотелось бы узнать какой командой вы создаете виртуальное окружение.

Однако исходя из вашего сообщения никакой ошибки нет, и оно говорит, что:

> создалось виртуальное окружение за 1935мс CPython3Windows(dest=P:\test5\venv, clear=False, global=False) with seeder FromAppData pip=latest setuptools=latest wheel=latest app_data_dir=C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv\seed-v1 via=copy

А вот место куда создалось окружение: P:\test5\venv

Для запуска войдите через терминал в директорию P:\test5 и пропишите в ней venv\Scripts\activate

Comment: Команда: virtualenv venv
Да, я знаю, как активировать. Но активация не происходит.
(venv) перед строкой терминала нет в данном случае.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать команду **python -m venv имя_окружения**, а затем запустить через **имя_окружения\Scripts\activate**

Comment: Так venv работает. Мне нужно именно virtualenv